# SAP HANA XSA Java user authentication by UAA

Tags: java, authentication, hana, hana-xs

Can someone give me some example how to do Java (Spring) user authentication by SAP HANA UAA service on **XSA**?

I saw many tutorial how to do it, but just for HTML5 + Node.js combo. PDF documentation is not specific about, how it works and I wasn't successful even following it step by step.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, for Spring using, firstly, you should create the UAA service instance, secondly you need create an AppRouter which binds with the UAA service instance, then you can make your java application bind with the same UAA service instance, after that, SSO based on SAML and Spring security can be used in your java application!

Hope the answer can be helpful!
BR,